# How to write to first n lines of file in bash

Tags: bash

I have a file `test.txt` with following content

```
first
second
AAA
BBB
CCC
DDD
```

And I want to remove the **first two lines** and add new values to the first two lines,

so,

once the first two lines are removed, file should look like this:

```
AAA
BBB
CCC
DDD
```

And then should add the two values to first line and then the second line, so the file would finally look like below:

```
new value at line 1
new value at line 2
AAA
BBB
CCC
DDD
```

So I tried the below command, but how can I remove the first two lines?

```
SERVER_HOSTNAME=$(hostname)
SERVER_IP=$(ip -o route get to 8.8.8.8 | sed -n 's/.*src \([0-9.]\+\).*/\1/p')
sed -i "1s/.*/$SERVER_HOSTNAME/" /tmp/test.txt
sed -i "2s/.*/$SERVER_IP/" /tmp/test.txt
```

My problem is, when I first remove the first two lines, and execute the above command, it will replace the line number 1 and two with new values, but I want to add them on the top so the others (already existing content will shift down) will go down.

Comment: Does this help? [How do I delete the first n lines of an ascii file using shell commands?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/37790/380303)

Comment: @Aplet123 to remove yes, but my code is replacing the values, not shifting down the content. any idea on that?

Comment: Why are you removing the first two lines first? Your `sed` command is *already* demonstrating that it can replace each line.

Comment: Note that standard UNIX filesystem semantics only let you do in-place replacement where the new content _has the exact same number of bytes as the old content_. In every other case (as when using `sed -i`), you're not just modifying the file, you're _replacing_ it entirely with a new file written from scratch. (The only exceptions involve nonstandard extensions, but even those generally only let you insert a block at a time _on block boundaries_, so you can't just add an extra line at any random place you like).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your existing `sed` already does what you want; it doesn't need you to remove the first two lines yourself first.

```
$ cat tmp.txt
first
second
AAA
BBB
CCC
DDD
$ SERVER_HOSTNAME=example.local
$ SERVER_IP=127.0.0.1
$ sed -i "1s/.*/$SERVER_HOSTNAME/;2s/.*/$SERVER_IP/" tmp.txt
$ cat tmp.txt
example.local
127.0.0.1
AAA
BBB
CCC
DDD
```

Comment: this doesn't do anything but gives an output

Comment: You can add `-i` yourself; I am merely demonstrating that you do not need to explicitly remove the first two lines yourself.

Comment: where should I add `-i` ?

Comment: The same place you have it now. What you have now already works. You just need to *not* edit the file yourself before running `sed`.

Comment: The call to `sed` in this answer doesn't "fix" anything; it's just a simpler version of what you already have.

Answer (score 2):

Could you please try following, written and tested with shown samples in GNU `awk`. This will edit 1st and 2nd lines with shell variable values and do an inplace save into Input_file itself.

In case you want to keep 1st line's content as well as print current content then one could remove `next` in `FNR==2` OR `FNR==1` conditions.

```
SERVER_HOSTNAME=$(hostname)
SERVER_IP=$(ip -o route get to 8.8.8.8 | sed -n 's/.*src \([0-9.]\+\).*/\1/p')
awk -v server_ip="$SERVER_IP" -v server_hostname="$SERVER_HOSTNAME" '
FNR==1{ print server_hostname; next}
FNR==2{ print server_ip;     ; next}
1
' Input_file > temp && mv temp Input_file
```

***Explanation for above solution:***

```
awk -v server_ip="$SERVER_IP" -v server_hostname="$SERVER_HOSTNAME" '
##Starting awk program from here, creating server_ip and server_hostname vars with respective shell vars.
FNR==1{ print server_hostname; next}
##Checking condition if this is 1st line then print server_hostname.
FNR==2{ print server_ip;     ; next}
##Checking condition if this is 2nd line then print server_ip here.
1
##1 will print current line.
' Input_file
##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Comment: You need not to remove first 2 lines and then insert 2 new lines, you could rather substitute 1st 2 lines which 2 new values, as simple as that.

Comment: what are the `input_file` `temp`

Comment: @JananathBanuka, this is just a way to do inplace in non gnu `awk`, it will save output into `temp` file then rename it to actual Input_file if `awk` command was successful to place output in `temp` file.

Comment: How to add another line to this? say I want to replace first three lines?

Comment: @JananathBanuka, I am sorry but 1 post 1 question only is encouraged on SO(hint: Create variables of new lines and print them accordingly in mentioned conditions), request you to please play around with these solutions and you could open a new question in case you would like to have guidance, cheers and happy learning.

Answer (score 2):

Don't run `sed -i` repeatedly. Instead, combine all your commands into one script.

```sh
sed -i "1s/.*/$(hostname)/
    2s/.*/$(ip -o route get to 8.8.8.8)/
    2s/.*src \([0-9.]\+\).*/\1/" /tmp/test.txt
```

This is rather brittle, though; in particular, it will break if either of the command substitutions produces a slash in their output.

(IIRC `ip` has options to produce machine-readable output; you should probably look into that instead of replacing out the parts you don't want.)

If you want to add, then delete, the `sed` `d` and `a` commands do that, respectively. But removing two and adding two is obviously equivalent to replacing two.

```
sed -i "1d
1a\hello
2d
2a\hello" file
```

Unfortunately, the `a` command is poorly standardized, and it's unclear how two `s` commands would not work, so I'm leaving this as a sketch.

Comment: This doesn't shift the content down, it replaces the lines

Comment: You can use `a` instead of `s` if you want to add a line; but your question looks like you want to delete two, then add two. If that's not what you want, can you please clarify?

Comment: i want to first remove first two lines and then add fill those first two lines with some values but whatever the content existed after the first two lines are removed, shouldn't be replaced by the new values. if you look at the final look at how file should look like you can get the idea

Comment: No, I can't see how that is different from changing the first two lines in one go. This sounds like you really have two separate questions.

Answer (score 1):

You may use this `gnu sed`:

```sh
gsed -i -e "1i\\$SERVER_HOSTNAME\n$SERVER_IP" -e '1,2{d;q;}' /tmp/test.txt
```

Or using POSIX sed:

```sh
sed -i.bak "1,2{d;q;};3i\\
$SERVER_HOSTNAME
3i\\
$SERVER_IP
" /tmp/test.txt
```

Comment: how to write this in one single line?

Comment: How to add another line to this? say we need to update the first three lines?

Comment: But this will again replaces the existing line in 3rd line and replaces it with the new value. Without replacing the 3rd row, can we shift the lines down and add some values to the 3rd line?